# Why Cucumber.options doesn't work in the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I was looking at a Gitlab CI script that defines some flags within the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable:

```
## etc...
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dspring.profiles.active=acc"

test-application:
  image: maven:3.6-jdk-11
  stage: test-run
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test $MAVEN_OPTS -DCucumber.options='--glue com/example/app'
## etc...
```

With the above script, the pipeline is successful.

However, I noticed that when I try to move the `-DCucumber.options='--glue com/example/app'` flag within the `MAVEN_OPTS` variable, e.g.

```
## etc...
MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dspring.profiles.active=acc -DCucumber.options='--glue com/example/app'"
## etc...
script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test $MAVEN_OPTS
## etc...
```

The pipeline now fails with the following message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.app'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.app'
```

**I was able to replicate this locally without Gitlab, so I discarded this being an issue with it.**

From what I understand, the `MAVEN_OPTS` variable is used by Maven during the set up of the JVM process so it seems like a place where I can add some flags for all my Maven commands without me having the need to add them explicitly later on. So, from my perspective, both scripts should be equivalent.

Is my understanding flawed? If so, can someone explain to me what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce this error with the following command:

```
$ java com/example/App
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.App
```

This suggests that either GitlabCI or Maven is reinterpreting the Commandline options. And looking at [MSHARED-750](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-750) and [cucumber-jvm/#596](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1596) it is probably Maven.

If you are using Cucumber v5+ you should use `cucumber.glue=com.example.app` instead of `cucumber.options`. See [Properties, Environment variables, System Options](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/core#properties-environment-variables-system-options). Alternatively with v5+ you can opt not to provide any glue at all as Cucumber will search for glue classes from the class path root by default.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be an issue with the space in the `-DCucumber.options='--glue com/example/app'` command when using `MAVEN_OPTS`. Thanks!